# Is there a way in SQL for selecting either table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to create a view which will result either table's results

if(exists(select 1 from table 1))
then select * from table1
else select * from table2

I have already googled but didn't find any suitable answer to do the same in redshift.

Comment: Why not `UNION` the tables and select them in one go?

Comment: You could use NVL or COALESCE, [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_NVL_function.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_NVL_function.html)

Comment: because I dont want to combine the results, I want results from table 1 if it exists else from table2.  moreover union will have performance issues.

Comment: That's precisely what functions like COALESCE do. `select coalesce(table1.value, table2.value) as value from ....` provided you have a method to join the tables.

Comment: @Isolated Firstly I dont have want to join table. both tables are having data in billions so joining/union will be very costly process.  If I have data in table 1 I want to use it if table 1 is empty then only I want to use table2.